# Once the checkbox is checked, the text is not displaying in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Once the `checkbox` is checked, then I would like to display the `input` text field. By default the checkbox should not be checked and the `token` input field should be hidden.

Now I am getting below error and not working properly.

Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`

```
 const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
 const [showToken, setShowToken] = useState({ show: false });

 const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setChecked(checked);
    if(checked === true){
      setShowToken({ show: true })
    }
  }

     <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} checked={checked}/>
           {
             showToken.show && (
             <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="token" type="text" placeholder="token"/>
               )
           }
     </label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can optimize code as,

1. Remove `const [showToken, setShowToken] = useState({ show: false });` line
2. Use `checked` prop for display textbox.
3. Use setChecked hook for set checkbox checked changes.So we do not need `handleClick` method anymore.

You can do this simply as follows,

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)} checked={checked}/>
           {
             checked ? (
             <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="token" type="text" placeholder="token"/>
               ) : (<div></div>)
           }
     </label>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: What does this line states....`onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)} ` ..is that `not checked` is passing to the state ?

Comment: `onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}` , that line says, call 'setChecked' method while the user click checkbox. As an example, in initial state , checkbox is not checked. because of that `checked` prop is false. Then user click checkbox, call the `setChecked(!checked)}` method. it means pass 'true' to the '`setChecked' method. Run the code snippet for better understand.

Comment: I was puzzled by the `!checked` why we need to say `!checked` here inside the setChecked()

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted your answer, awesome reply..